# Adding more and more <timepicker> issue. if one gets changed it changes all of them

Tags: javascript, html, angular, timepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have a little problem, I repeat timepicker with *ngFor, but it's not working properly if I changed the time in one of them, it changes in all. And all have a different id. AN IDEA TO MAKE THE WORk PROPERLY?`

COMPONENT.HTML :

```
<div id="schedule" *ngFor="let i of Arr(num).fill(1)" 
     style="display: -webkit-inline-flex">
  <timepicker id="timer" class="schedulItem" style="margin-top:-28px" 
     [(ngModel)]="mytime" [showMeridian]="isMeridian"  
     [minuteStep]="mstep" (ngModelChange)="changed()">
  </timepicker>
  <button (click)="addSchedule()"> + </button>
</div>
```

COMPONENT.TS:

```
Arr = Array; //Array type captured in a variable
num:number = 1;
mytime: Date;

addSchedule() {
  this.num = this.num + 1 ;
  var length = document.querySelectorAll('.schedul').length
  var time = document.getElementById("timer");
  time.id +=  length;
}

changed(): void {
  var time = this.mytime.getHours() + ":" + this.mytime.getMinutes();
  console.log(time);    
}
```

Comment: i dont see why they would have a different id each, they should all have the same id `id="timer"` which will lead to the behaviour you describe

Comment: I understand but I want to be able to modify each one because I have to set several time intervals in the only day

Comment: an idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! the model was the problem `[(ngModel)]="mytime"`. All time pickers to the same model and one gets changed it changes all of them.